# On the strange 1.7 pt offset when positioning a + sign at (0,0) node with the lmr 13 fontsize

Tags: fonts, fontsize, tikz-node

I get a strange 1.7 pt offset when positioning a + sign at (0,0) node with the lmr 13 fontsize.
When using the default font and default font size no offset appears, red + shown below.
Do you know how to get rid of these undesirable offsets for a non default font and fontsize?
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\newcommand{\labelf}{\usefont{T1}{lmr}{m}{n}\fontsize{13}{\baselineskip} \selectfont}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [ help lines,xstep=1.7pt,ystep=1.7pt] (-3.4pt,-3.4pt) grid (3.4pt,3.4pt);
\node [font=\labelf]at (0,0){+};
\node [text=red]at (0,0){+};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could it be the space before `\selectfont`?

Comment: smart answer. Would you please put ur ans below then I accept.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an extra space in your definition of `labelf`:

```
\fontsize{13}{\baselineskip} \selectfont
                            ^
```

This space matters because `node[font=\f]{\g}`
is essentially `node{\f\g}`.  This also explains
why the shift is in positive-x direction.